# In PHP/Opencart, how to put an array inside another array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, opencart

I'm newbie in PHP and Opencart and I want to show a **list of products** with their appropriate **categories**, but I don't know how to manage it with array:

```
$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

$results = $this->model_catalog_profile->getProducts();

if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {

        // Categories
        $categories = $this->model_profile_profile->getProductCategories($result['product_id']);

        $data['product_categories'] = array();

        foreach ($categories as $category_id) {
            $category_info = $this->model_profile_category->getCategory($category_id);
            if ($category_info) {
                $data['product_categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category_info['category_id'],
                    'name' => $category_info['name']
                );
            }
        }


        $data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'       => $image,
            'name'        => $result['name'],
            'product_categories'    => $data['product_categories'][]
            )
        );

    }

    return $this->load->view('module/latest', $data);
}
```

And here is the code view:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<div class="profile-thumb transition">
    <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>

        <div id="product-category" class="" style="height: 120px; overflow: auto;">
            <?php foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) { ?>
```

">

Comment: Try this `array_push($data['products'], $new_arr);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, I'm sorry, I really didn't understand what to do or where to use this code!

Comment: instead of `$data['products'][] = array(....)` use `array_push($data['products'], $new_arr);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, Would you please post an Answer The Question? I really don't understand. array_push($data['products'], $new_arr) = array(
     'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
     'thumb'       => $image,
     'name'        => $result['name'],
     WHERE SHOULD I ADD CATEGORIES?
     )
    );

Comment: Do you need to insert `$data['product_categories']` into `$data['products']`?

Comment: Just remove `[]` from `'product_categories'    => $data['product_categories'][]`. It should be `'product_categories'    => $data['product_categories']`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, Thanks! It's fixed. I followed the code of category-subcategory page and I approached the same solution as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS per the discussion, Just remove `[]` from `'product_categories' => $data['product_categories'][]`. It should be `'product_categories' => $data['product_categories']`

**Updated Portion:**

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
    'name'        => $result['name'],
    'product_categories'    => $data['product_categories']
    )
);
```

This may be worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track here, although I think this might be more appropriate to what you're trying to achieve:

```
if ($results) {

  // For best practice, let's define the products key value first
  $data['products'] = array();

  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
    // Create the array for our product
    $product = array(
      'product_id'         => $result['product_id'],
      'thumb'              => $image,
      'name'               => $result['name'],
      'product_categories' => array()
    );

    // Fetch the categories for this product
    $categories = $this->model_profile_profile->getProductCategories($result['product_id']);

    foreach ($categories as $category_id)
    {
        $category_info = $this->model_profile_category->getCategory($category_id);
        if (!$category_info) continue;

        // Assign our category information a new category array
        $category = [
          'category_id' => $category_info['category_id'],
          'name'        => $category_info['name']
        ];

        // Push the new category array to our products array
        array_push($product['product_categories'], $category);

        // Optionally, free up some memory
        unset($category_info);
    }

    // Now push our new product array to our data array
    array_push($data['products'], $product);

    // Optionally, we can perform some clean up
    unset($categories);
}

return $this->load->view('module/latest', $data);
```

What we've done here is define our `$data['products']` array first - this just makes the code much easier to read and quickly scan through.

Then, we've focused on creating a `$product` array before worrying about categories; that way we can create our `product_categories` key within the array, with a blank array as the initial value.

Next, after we've fetched the categories using `getProductCategories`, we enumerate through the returned array, creating a new `$category` array along the way, and then using `array_push` to add it to our `$product['product_categories']` array.

Lastly for the loop, after we've fully constructed our new `$product` array, we use `array_push` again to add it to our `$data['products']` array.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I used "'product_category' => $cats," and it fixed the problem.